# How do I choose a random image from an array and use it as a source for other images in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web

I am trying to make a website and I need random images to be generated and then used as an input button thingy.

When I try to use the results of the thing the image does not show up.

The thing i need help with is displaying the image bc the code that picks the random image like has it under a name but idk how to use to name as a source for a button thing

I want the generated image to replace the button if that makes any sense

Comment: Show us da code

Comment: okay!! how and also the code is a MESS bc most of it is from this website and im just editing it bc i had no idea how 2 start

Comment: Also sry i just started coding in this language today so im like so bad

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to do this:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('You clicked!')">
      <img src="" id="button_img" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script>

  //array of links for images
  var array_of_images = [
    "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/97-974332_yellow-duck-png-download-image-transparent-background-rubber.png",
    "https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/07/31/78089_make_512x512.png",
    "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/97-974413_rubber-duck-png-transparent-background-duck-clipart-png.png"
    ];

  //generate random number form 0-3
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

  //using the random number to choose a link from the array
  document.getElementById('button_img').src = array_of_images[randomNum];

</script>
```

Comment: Im looking for like the button to have the image and then when i click the button the whole button changes to the generated image. Is that possible?

Comment: I edited it a bit bc i was looking for it to do something a bit different but i have like part of it. The right image shows and then it lets me click it and the image changes but it doesnt change to the generated image

Comment: OMG! I edited it a tiny bit more and it workssss! Im so excited tysm